# Using a .Net Workstation Program With a LAMP Server

Tags: .net, lamp

I am currently working on a project for a company with a Ubuntu LAMP server set up.  All the workstations are on Windows XP/Vista. What we are trying to do is create a program to track parts in our warehouse. Server side would be programmed in PHP.  However, I was thinking about using C# on the workstation side.

Is this possible? If so, is this practical? What kind of problems could arise from something like this?

Comment: It's possible ... but, do you really need a thick client? It seems that an obvious path would be to do the client interface in PHP as well. If you can you explain further what needs you have for your client, we can answer if it's practical, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In a client-server architecture, it doesn't matter what technology the client or server are using, only what communication protocol they use.

In this case it seems like it would be http. I caution this only as there is no contract for pure HTTP, and I would recommend a WS format like SOAP (which still uses http as the transport).

Answer (score 0):

I assume the reason you need a client app at all (rather than just building a web-based app and installing nothing on the workstations but a browser) is because you have some sort of bar-code or RFID scanner that you use for tracking goods in and out of the warehouse, and you need to interface with it.

Firstly, I'd highly recommend finding a way of avoiding installing a client-side application. If you can make it all web-based, you will have less code to maintain, and no distribution/installation concerns.

If you absolutely must have a client-side app, look at making the server-side RESTful (google this if you don't know what it is), and you can utilise the existing HTTP libraries in the .NET framework to send and receive data to/from the server.